# Desrealizar json en C# xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

Hola amigos estoy usando Xamarin Forms y HttpClient para hacer un post, todo bien hasta ahí, recibo mi respuesta todo en orden, pero cuando intento desceralizarlo pum!!!

obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TrustFund.Models_.ResponceTrustPass]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'responce', line 1, position 12
```

Este justo el punto donde pasa

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var username = Username.Text;
    var pass = Pass.Text;

    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                 {
                    { "username",  "x" },
                    { "pass", "xxxx" }
                 };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://x.x.com",
        content);





    switch (response.StatusCode) {
        case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):




            string xjson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //var myobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Project>(xjson);


            //192.168.1.74
            //Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xjson);

            var json_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponceTrustPass>>(xjson); //justo aquí
```

Esta es mi clase modelo de la respuesta:

```
using System;
namespace x.Models_
{

    // esta clase recibe el /m/confirm-pass
    public class Responcex
    {
        public Responce responce { get; set; }
    }

    public class User_Info
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string id_client { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastnameP { get; set; }
        public string lastnameM { get; set; }
        public string pass { get; set; }
        public string mail { get; set; }
        public object admin { get; set; }
        public int user { get; set; }
        public object owner { get; set; }
        public object gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime datenac { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string calle { get; set; }
        public string colonia { get; set; }
        public object estado { get; set; }
        public int cp { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
        public int id_usercreated { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Responce
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public User_Info user_info { get; set; }
    }
}
```

y mi json

```
{
    "responce": {
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1NjA0NDI1MDksImV4cCI6MTU2MDQ0MjgwOX0.a2p5bY7OvJuWcedf3XVSnB19f87ACu-zAj0DvaeB3Nk",
        "user_info": {
            "id": 832,
            "id_client": "a00owjgyqrajjkawgess",
            "created_at": "2019-05-21T18:06:48.000Z",
            "username": "kiko",
            "name": "x",
            "lastnameP": "x",
            "lastnameM": "x",
            "pass": "$2a$10$oaqRrPE0G9vzbMHceC6Feu088kw1BF5wGDsL4DluFHae9qL8GX79q",
            "mail": "k@j.com",
            "admin": null,
            "user": 1,
            "owner": null,
            "gender": null,
            "datenac": "2015-02-20T00:00:00.000Z",
            "phone": "9611545746",
            "calle": "s",
            "colonia": "s",
            "estado": null,
            "cp": 72182,
            "img": "https://x.s3.amazonaws.com/0c0f330372e4a0d82b84576d7319a0086f03.jpg",
            "id_usercreated": 0,
            "status": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que `ResponceTrustPass` es `Responcex`, entonces el problema es que el json del request es un objeto y no una matriz de objeto.

El error que dejas lo dice explicitamente:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TrustFund.Models_.ResponceTrustPass]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> ---
>
> No se puede deserializar el objeto JSON actual en el tipo lista porque el tipo requiere una matriz JSON para deserializar correctamente.

En general, el error se refiere a que tu json es un objeto y no un array o matriz de objeto. Por lo tanto deberias quitar el `List<>` y dejarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
var json_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponceTrustPass>(xjson);
```